# Расширение из другой таблицы в зависимости от типа

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Делаю учёт доходов/расходов. Имеются таблицы: `operations`, `incomes`, `expenditures`. Операции могут быть двух типов: доходные и расходные.

Используя Eloquent мне бы хотелось через свойство `extended` получать модели с данными из таблиц `incomes` и `expenditures` в зависимости от типа операции. Если тип `income`, то из таблицы `incomes`, а если `expenditure`, из таблицы `expenditures`. Но я не знаю, как это сделать.

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: немного неясна структура таблиц. Покажите, пожалуйста, миграции.

Comment: да и архитектура тут страдает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посидев за документацией я понял, что мне нужны полиморфические отношения. А именно один к одному.

В моделе `Operation` у меня есть метод `operationable`, который, в зависимости от типа `operationable_type` возвращает ту или иную модель операции.

Структура таблиц выглядит так (теперь):

```
operations
- id
- name
- account_id
- operationable_id - идентификатор расширенной модели
- operationable_type - тип расширенной модели

incomes
- id
- value

expenditures
- id
- value
```

В модели `Operation` имеется метод `operationable`:

```
public function operationable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

В моделях `Income` и `Expenditure` имеется метод `operation` (обратная ссылка):

```
public function operation()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\Operation', 'operationable');
}
```

**Примеры**

Таблица `operations`:

```
id    ^ name        ^ account_id    ^ operationable_id    ^ operationable_type
1     | Зарплата    | 1             | 1                   | App\Income
2     | Продукты    | 1             | 1                   | App\Expenditure
3     | Кредит      | 1             | 2                   | App\Expenditure
```

Таблица `incomes`:

```
id    ^ value
1     | 20000
```

Таблица `expenditures`:

```
id    ^ value
1     | 1000
2     | 5500
```

PHP:

```
$operation = Operation::find(1); // абстрактная операция
$income = $operation->operationable; // операция дохода
echo $income->value; // выведет 20000

$operation = Operation::find(2);
$expenditure = $operation->operationable; // операция расхода
echo $expenditure->value; // выведет 1000

// Выведет true
var_export($operation->id == $operation->operationable->operation->id);
```

Подробнее о полиморфических отношениях можно узнать здесь: [Документация Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships).